# How to increase height of text view when i type return key in key board?

Tags: ios, uitextview

How to increase height of text view when i type return key in key board?

please give me solution .

there are many views on top.
need i to set frame of all view or just decreasing height of table view i will get solution?

Comment: you have to set both frame textview as well as tableview....

Comment: Do you want to find the new height required for the textview and apply them as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, every time you hit 'Enter' on keyboard, you have to resize (height) the `UITextView`, and also resize (height) the `UITableView` accordingly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will set the height of the TextView according to it's content.

```
[txtAddress setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90, 280, [self contentSizeRectForTextView:txtAddress])];
```

Method for TextView height:

```
- (CGFloat)contentSizeRectForTextView:(UITextView *)txtView
{
[txtView.layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:txtView.textContainer];
CGRect textBounds = [txtView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:txtView.textContainer];
CGFloat height = (CGFloat)ceil(textBounds.size.height + txtView.textContainerInset.top + txtView.textContainerInset.bottom);
return height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting new frame size, your view frame origin should still be the same but the frame height.

```
[textView setFrame: CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x,textView.frame.origin.y,textVie.frame.size.width,<new height>)];
```

Comment: what about table view.table view  y point and height also need to be changed?

Comment: see my second screen shot.i am getting that error.what to do

Comment: you should also adjust the height of the table row to the height of your textview..